# Cannot GET / error running hello world in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

Full Github project: https://github.com/pbrianmackey/uiexperiment

I run

`webpack-dev-server --content-base deployment/`

Then go to `http://localhost:8080/`, Error

> Cannot GET /

I think the problem is a misconfiguration of webpack.  I checked by webpack.config.js file and don't see a problem.  How can I fix this so I get my hello world example?

It could be a routing problem too.  I think I can use this website without react-router, but I could be wrong.  There are no errors in webpacks output on the console.

#### index.js

```js
import "babel-polyfill";//for flipping IE
import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
var App = require('./app');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Turns out I had index.html in the wrong place.  From the webpack [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html):

> To load your bundled files, you will need to create an index.html file
>   in the build folder from which static files are served (--content-base
>   option).

I made a copy of index.html in a new folder I called `deployment` to match what I specified in the [output.path](https://github.com/pbrianmackey/uiexperiment/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L13)

Answer (score 18):

In the `webpack.config.js` put this :

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Comment: This is only relevant if your using react router

Comment: @Liam This is relevant in any SPA using client-side routing regardless of framework

Answer (score 7):

In webpack-dev-server documentation, there is an `writeToDisk` option to solve this problem [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-). 
It will store all files on disk instead of memory.
Example from my config:

```
devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    writeToDisk: true,
    proxy: {
        '/': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
}
```

Comment: `writeToDisk` is not exist

`- options has an unknown property 'writeToDisk'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }`

Comment: @elliotching It's under the devMiddleware for Webpack 4
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdevmiddleware

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and what fixed it for me was adding the following code to my webpack.config.js file.

```
static: {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '/')
}
```

Add this as an additional option to devServer:

'/' indicates the root folder for your app.

Answer (score 2):

- You have to be running node.js version 10.13.0+.
- Add an absolute path with the exit point 'dist'.
- Webpack HTML plugin is required (to access the plugin).
- Clear your dev server cache ctrl + c & in task manager.

My webpack.config.js file looks like this.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './starting-code/code/main.js',
    output: 
           {
              path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
              filename:'main.js',
           },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './starting- 
              code/index.html' })],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/i,
                type: "asset/resource"
            },
            {
                test: /\.txt$/i,
                type: 'asset/source'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource"
            },

        ]
    }
}
```